Latin Palaeography [a Rental c. 1450} - Could someone help with abbreviated forms/symbols?
I have been looking at palaeography books and online, and am learning slowly, but I am stuck on some of the Latin symbols and letters in abbreviated words.
No.1 (on image/extract) looks like 'bo' then a sideways 8 - I can't find this sideways 8 anywhere !
No 2 (on image/extract) ends with a special 'p' for 'per' or 'par' but the preceding four minims all look the same - is it possible to decipher what their letters might be ? *SUBSEQUENT EDIT - I have now worked this one out - it is nu[per], so no need to reply to this question. *
No. 3 ends with an 'a, but are the first two letters 'th' ? *SUBSEQUENT EDIT - I am now thinking the middle may be a v-like 'p'with a symbol above for missing letters, so this may be 'terra'? *
No. 4 looks slightly like 'iy' for '2' but with an unusual superscript - or is it something else ? SUBSEQUENT EDIT - I now see this is ij for '2', with a superscript 's' for shillings. So no need to reply to this question !

